# how to make variables and debug extension working in jupyterlab

Tags: variables, debugging, autocomplete, highlight, jupyter-lab

I downloaded several extensions in jupyterlab for debugging and watching variables or autocomplete code or highlight code

I don't know how to make them work I (enable extension manager) but nothing work of them
Should I write code to make them work? or I should find these extensions work by default
I want to make debugging for codes and see matrices and variables while working

attached some of extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFUbB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrnom.png)

[extensions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRh1d.png)

Comment: If you have a specific issue with jupyterlab-lsp please open an issue [here](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) providing precise description of what you installed, what you expect to work and what does not work. Also, please do not install jupyterlab-lsp AND jupyterlab-go-to-definition (only lsp). Also no one will be able to help you because you have not provided sufficient details (versions of JupyterLab, version of extension, explanation of what "does not work" mean for you). Please put more effort into formulating questions.

Comment: Also, please make sure that you follow the official [installation instructions](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp#installation) for jupyterlab-lsp. You should not install @krassowski/completion-theme manually and in general avoid using `jupyter labextension` in the latest version of JupyterLab if there are pip install equivalents. In latest version of JupyterLab (which you use), you should NOT install debugger as it is included by default.

Comment: I want to know when I install extension is it work automatically or I write code or do something to make it work

Comment: Ok, I see there is a screenshot of versions. Please do not provide text as screenshots it is  very difficult to read, especially for users who have eyesight issues. Please paste the text from the terminal into the question.

Comment: It will work automatically if you install it following installation instructions. The installation instructions (for jupyerlab-lsp) include installing a language server. I am afraid that if you keep this question as-is the community will start down voting it soon. I do understand that you wish to have nice IDE out of JupyterLab, but asking about two (or in fact three) distinct extensions in one question is lacking focus and therefor difficult to answer.

Comment: I can help you with jupyterlab-lsp (as one of the authors) but please read the installation instructions first ([here](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp#installation) and [there](https://jupyterlab-lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html)) and uninstall `jupyterlab-go-to-definition` and `theme-completion`.

Comment: how to check language server before installing jupyerlab-lsp please tell me steps for installing in details if you please

Comment: You would need to know the name of the language server that you wanted to install (e.g. python-lsp-server, jedi-language-server, etc) and use `pip list` or `conda list` (depending on what tool you used for installation). The detailed installation instructions are provided in the readme and in the documentation. Have you read them? Is there any particular step that you have a problem with? I would generally recommend to start from a clean virtual environment and give a little bit more thought before installing multiple extensions at once without learning about each of them first.

Comment: I installed python-lsp-server 1.0.1 is that right? and I have python 3.9.2 , jupyterlab-lsp 3.6.0 jupyterlab-server 2.5.0 ,  now what i should do